# So confused about Scala Class definition

Tags: scala

All:

I am on my third day of scala study. Using book "begin scala".

It defines a class:

```
class Book( var title:String)
```

then instantiate an object:

```
val book = new Book("Beginning Scala")
```

It mentions one thing that

> If you decompile this code, you can see the generated mutator method
>   with an unusual name,title_$eq.

```
scala> :javap -c Book
Compiled from "Book.scala"
public class Book {
public java.lang.String title();
//.......
public void title_$eq(java.lang.String);
//.........
public Book(java.lang.String);
//........
}

So when you set the field, like so

book.title("new title")

Scala converts it to the following:

Book.title_$eq("Beginning Scala")
```

I am not sure if I understand this right, but when I try:

```
book.title("new title")
```

THe scala console tells me that:

```
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("new title")
 required: Int
       book.title("new title")
```

I wonder if scala does not allow external call to a setter function, why the author mention like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What the segment about decompilation is trying to tell you is that it actually sets up the accessor to be assignable, e.g:

```
book.title = "Beginning Scala"
```

This is possible because the assignment is really just syntactic sugar for the auto-generated method `Book.title_$eq(v: String). You could use that long form if you wanted:

```
book.title_$eq("Beginning Scala")
```

If you wanted to set up the getters and setters manually you'd write something like this:

```
class Book() {
  private var _title = ""
  def title = _title
  def title_=(v: String):Unit = _title = v
}
```

allowing you to do this:

```
val book = new Book()
book.title = "bar"
println(book.title) // "bar"
book.title_=("foo")
println(book.title) // "foo"
book.title_$eq("baz")
println(book.title) // "baz"
```

As you can see, the `title_=` method can be used via the assignment syntactic sugar, the `_=` method or the `_$eq` encoding.

Comment: thanks, I get this now. Could you please help with another quesion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31956486/confuse-about-scala-private-field-variable