# Confuse about scala private field variable

Tags: scala

I am on my third day of scala study. Using book "begin scala".

Te author uses an example to show the diff between variable define with val var And without var val:

```
class Book(private val title: String) {
   def printTitle(b: Book) {
       println(b.title)
   }
}
```

And in the console:

```
scala> val book = new Book("Beginning Scala")
book: Book = Book@ea05be
scala> book.printTitle(new Book("Beginning Erlang"))
Beginning Erlang
```

Here what confused me is not with/without val var, but the private modifier:

I am not sure if I understand private right, but if scala want **title as private field**, then **why it allows others to access it from outside**, I thought the prinTitle should not be able to access  new Book("Beginning Erlang")'s title field

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value `title` is *private* to the class, not to the instance, Since the method `printTitle` is a member of the class, it can access private values of other instances.

If you wanted `title` to be private to the instance, you would use the `private[this]` modifier instead.

Further, the `private[package]` modifier, where `package` is the name of the package the definition occurs in, can share the private member with the package. For example

```
package com.sample.foo

class Book(private[foo] title: String)
```

would be accessible to all code in package `com.sample.foo`

Comment: Thanks. I guess I may need a little time to understand whole of this. To verify I correctly understand what you mean: Will this "The value title is private to the class, not to the instance" be understood as "The value title is private to the other class type, not to the instance generated from that class" ?

Comment: @Kuan Correct. The intention is that instances already know each other's internals, since they are of the same kind and therefore get to access them. But since sometimes you really want to tightly control internals, the private[this] modifier exists to restrict access to just the instance.

Comment: I read that part in the book again, to verify I understand how class works correct: Can I understand as that all fields in Scala class is accessed via getter and setter function rather than directly access that variable? So PRIVATE limit the access to the getter setter function(I am not sure if it  allowing only memeber method, or totally remove getter setter) to make the world outside has no way to access that variable?

Answer (score 3):

`title` is a private field for class `Book`.

In Java you write this like:

```
class Book {
    private final String title;

    Book(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void printTitle(b: Book) {
       System.out.println(b.title)
    }
 }
```

I think the function `printTitle` may be somewhat confusing because in both java and scala it would usually not be implemented as an instance method.
I would write something like that as a static method in java. And in scala I would put it into a *companion object* (to throw yet another alien concept at a confused scala newby ;)):

```
class Book(private val title: String)

object Book {
    def printTitle(b: Book) {
       println(b.title)
   }
}
```

So Book has access to any *private* field of any instance of Book.

If you want to restrict the access of title to an instance of Book you would write something like:

```
class Book(private[this] val title: String) {
   // no longer compiles
   // def printTitle(b: Book) {
   //    println(b.title)
   //}

   def printTitle() {
       println(title)
   }
}
```

Comment: THanks. After reading this, I feel the concept of PRIVATE is diff in JAVA and Scala(and here it is more complex and flexible)